# db2 installation on Centos 6.0

Tags: db2, centos

To start with can DB2-C-Express 10.1 be installed on CentOs 6.0 ? I am trying with the Light version . 
I tried installing it but I am unable to execute commands like ./db2sampl , ./db2 from the bin after the installation. 
Any pointers ? Any good links with steps for installation ? 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with the "full" versions of DB2.  In general, the installer should have created an instance owner such as "db2inst1".   Log in in that account and try it. the .bashrc file should already include include it.   If you would like to run it from another account, source the db2profile file in the instance home:

```
. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
```

The other account would need the correct privileges to execute administrative commands.